# How to lowercase column values within a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe imported from a csv file that contains a column that I need to have lowercase values. The data is mixed, column for example looks like this:

```
Column1
HTYKS45
3874_YR
PIDRESO
PID-4_Y
```

Here is the code I have tried, and from what I have researched it seems like it should work, but is not. Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.Dataframe(pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\myfile.csv"))
file['Column1'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

Comment: You need to assign the results back,  file['Column1'] = file['Column1'].astype(str).str.lower()

Comment: @Vaishali since you responded first, I'd like to give you the answer vote.

Comment: its a duplicate question and I would recommend that you close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically

```
file['Column1'] = file['Column1'].astype(str).str.lower()
```